# Animation of Jumps in Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have created a map using Leaflet and added an icon marker to it. I would like to apply a jumping effect to the marker when the mouse hovers over it. I have implemented the effect, but I am experiencing an issue where the marker moves to the top left corner of the map when the mouse passes over it. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this behavior? Thank you very much.

Js

```
    var marker = L.marker([4.81476666666667, -75.6994888888889], { icon: customIcon }).addTo(mymap);

marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
    marker.getElement().classList.add('marker-icon');
    marker.getElement().style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -100%)'; 
  });
  
  marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
    marker.getElement().classList.remove('marker-icon');
    marker.getElement().style.transform = ''; 
  });
```

CSS

```
.marker-icon {
  position: relative;
  animation: jump 0.5s infinite alternate;

}

@keyframes jump {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: View `console.log(marker.getElement());` then you will know to use translate3d ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a library for this.
There you have more options to set - [Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing](https://github.com/hosuaby/Leaflet.SmoothMarkerBouncing)

But if you insist on your solution, below is the beginning of the code from which you can start.

```js
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
};

const zoom = 18;

const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

const marker = L.marker([52.22983, 21.011728])
  .addTo(map)
  .bindPopup("Center Warsaw");

let root = document.documentElement;

marker.on("mouseover", function (e) {
  e.target._icon.classList.add("marker-icon");

  const { x, y } = e.layerPoint;

  root.style.setProperty("--position-x", x + "px");
  root.style.setProperty("--position-y", y + "px");
});

marker.on("mouseout", function (e) {
  e.target._icon.classList.remove("marker-icon");
  root.style.removeProperty("--position-x");
  root.style.removeProperty("--position-y");
});
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.marker-icon {
  position: relative;
  animation: jump 0.5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes jump {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(var(--position-x), var(--position-y), 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(
      var(--position-x),
      calc(var(--position-y) - 10px),
      0
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css"
    />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    
    <div id="map"></div>
```